# R - Count number of "True" value in matrix columns and assign "False"

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix the looks like this:

```
set.seed(1234)
m <- matrix(round(runif(50,0,4)), ncol=10)
m <- (m>2)
```

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
[1,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

For each column, I need to count the number of `TRUE`s. If the total number of `TRUE`s per column is lower than 3,
then I need each `TRUE` in that column to become `FALSE`.

For this example, the expected output would be:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

My real matrix is much larger (100,000 x 2,000), so the solution needs to be fast.

Any hints on how to get there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, finding the columns' counts can be done with `colSums:

```r
colSums(m)
#  [1] 1 2 2 1 0 3 0 3 1 2
```

Then, just like you're overwriting the `m` matrix with your `m <- m > 2`, you can overwrite select columns with a conditional:

```r
m[, colSums(m) < 3] <- FALSE
m
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `apply`

```
m[, apply(m, 2, sum) < 3] <- FALSE
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
m %>% 
   as.data.frame %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., sum(.) < 3, FALSE)))
```